# Print sys.stderr along normal print in python

Tags: python

Recently I wrote some code and I want to format my output with minimal formatting, such that I combine `sys.stderr` and `print` to print some more important part in red colour. It works well, however when I try print "normally" -i.e. with use of `print`- a text followed by some red coloured text with `sys.stderr` in the same line using `comma` after the `print` statement, at the next standard `print` statement the interpreter insert a `space` before the printable text. How could I avoid this?

```
import sys

print "nana", "dada %d " % 2, 
print >> sys.stderr, "hey"

print "nana", "dada %d" % 2,
print >> sys.stderr, " hey"
```

**Output:**

```
nana dada 2 hey
 nana dada 2 hey
```

Note: I don't want to use any third party module, because I mainly use my code inside of `Spyder`'s internal console, thus I can't see any other colour, than `stderr`'s red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic insertion of a space gets confused by the fact that you use two different files.  You should write to at least one of the two files using sys.stdout.write() or sys.stderr.write().  For example:

```
print "nana", "dada %d " % 2,
sys.stderr.write("hey")         # no newline
print                           # print the newline here
```

Comment: Glamorous, thank you! Actually I always used `sys.stderr` as copy/paste from other code and there is not much really clear documentation all around.